# Redirect All URL's With A Particular Pathname To A Certain View - LARAVEL

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, laravel-mix

Okay i'm running two react projects using laravel, a website and an admin section. I want both apps rendered on separate pages because their css would clash.
So in my `web.php` i have this `Route::view('/{path?}', 'app');`, but this redirects all my routes to my `app.blade.php` view.

I'm justing wondering if i can have a route that redirects any route with a specific pathname, let's say: `mydomainname.com/admin` to my `admin.blade.php`. Then every other route goes to my `app.blade.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay i was able to pull it off. Erkan Ozkok's answer gave me a hint.

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::view('/{path?}', 'admin');
});

Route::any('{query}', 
function() { return view('app'); })
->where('query', '.*');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Route::prefix like this:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('users', function () {
        // Matches The "/admin/users" URL
    });
});
```

Comment: so if i do this `Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::view('/{path?}', 'admin');
});` . How can i make all other url's redirect to another view